# duda con ciclos y ciclos anidados en ruby

Tags: ruby, bucles

tengo una gran duda, no entiendo muy bien como se aplican los ciclos anidados, quiero realizar un ejercicio y no entiendo como responderlo me piden que al colocar una cantidad X de numeros te vayan colocando en columnas el numero y su serie dependiendo en que fila va

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

codigo que estoy utilizando

```
n = ARGV[0].to_i
x = 0

n.times do |i|
  print "1"

  i.times do |j|
    print "2"

    j.times do |k|
      print "3"

      k.times do |l|
        print "4"
      end
    end
  end

  print "\n"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que los ciclos anidados sí los entiendes, creo que tu duda va más en la lógica del algoritmo que necesitas para reproducir la lista.

Te recomiendo primero resolver el problema en papel y después llevarlo al código, así podrás determinar el número de *bucles* que necesitarás (en tu programa estás agregando un *bucle* por cada número en la lista, pero realmente no necesitas tantos).

Simplificando el proceso:

- Se deben imprimir `n` número de líneas.
- Cada línea se compone de 1 a `n` números, de acuerdo al número de línea.

Dos *bucles* son los necesarios, no más. Ahora, ¿cuál es la lógica?

- En el primer *bucle* cada línea muestra un número entre 1 y `n` el cual llamaremos `i`:

  ```
  (1..n).each do |i|
    print i
    print "\n"
  end
  ```

  Por ejemplo, si lo ejecutamos con `n = 5` obtenemos el número de cada línea:

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  ```
- En el segundo *bucle* cada línea muestra todos los números entre 1 e `i` (número de línea):

  ```
  (1..n).each do |i|
    (1..i).each do |j|
      print j
    end

    print "\n"
  end
  ```

  Por ejemplo, si lo ejecutamos también con `n = 5` obtenemos el resultado esperado:

  ```
  1
  12
  123
  1234
  12345
  ```